# Why don't I have to declare a value in my boolean if statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

Here is some simple code:

```
var x = 4;

if (x) {
alert("true");
} else {
  alert("false");
}
```

Does JavaScript automatically know that the first alert is when `x == 4` and the the second alert is when `x != 4`? Why don't I have to declare `if (x == 4)` in my if statement?

Comment: No, it doesn't "know" that. If you change `x` to a non-zero number other than `4`, it will still be truth-y. If you want to log based on whether `x == 4`, *write `x == 4`*.

Comment: Dear @nickj4495, Welcome to Stack Overflow. please read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60104287/6877799), It has a good lesson for you to know JavaScript better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JavaScript is a dynamically typed language, meaning that you do not have to specify a type for a variable declaration, during certain scenarios (such as the one you have provided), it has to automatically detect the type and cast/convert it to an appropriate type if needed in a technique known as **coercion**.

In your scenario, JavaScript is expecting a boolean as an argument to the if-statement but what is provided is rather a number. So in this case, JavaScript attempts to coerce this integer value to a boolean. The strategy used by JavaScript to coerce numbers to integers is as follows:

**If the number is 0, JavaScript coerces it to false, while for any other number, it is coerced to true.**

For strings,
**if the string is an empty string (`""`), it is coerced to false, while for any other non-empty string value, it's coerced to true.**

Values that are coerced to `false` are termed **falsy values** while those that are coerced to `true` are termed **truthy values**.

Hope this helps.
For further readings, [check this out](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/)

Answer (score 0):

Like that you are checking if (x **has a value other than 0 null or undefined** which is `true`),

but if you want to test change `x to 5` and change your condition to `x === 4`,

it will  throw you to the `else` section.

```js
var x = 4;

if (x === 5) {
  alert("true");
} else {
  alert("false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are checking that x is truthy. Meaning that it has a value other than 0.

The opposite of truthy is called falsy. 
if(!x) would return true if x is false, 0, "", null, undefined or NaN

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you need to know more about [type coercion](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/types-grammar/ch4.md). In JavaScript sometimes some types change its nature. In your example, the `number` type is changed to `boolean` so the `if` accept it and the first alert raised.